# readonly class not really read only

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have my simple class definition as follow:

```
public class class1 { public int a; }

private class1 _myclass;
//define a public readonly class
public class1 myclass {
  get { return _myclass; }
  //set { _myclass = value; }
}
```

and in my code the following line is not accepted:

```
myclass = new myclass(); //class is read only
```

however I can still write the following:

```
myclass.a = 2; //i can edit readonly class element
```

I want to prevent this and make elements of my readonly class unavailable.

**edit**: I forgot to mention that I still want to access it this way:

```
_myclass.a = 2; //passing from private class is intended purpose
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "immutable", not "readonly".

Comment: By 'unavailable' you mean you don't wont to allow modifications or reading and modifications?

Comment: actually your class is readonly. because you can not change the reference. only you can change what is inside. as CodeCaster suggested you need immutable class which you have to limit its functionalities by your self.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary can I still access its elements from the private reference with an immutable class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readonly will only stop you from replacing the myclass reference, you're still allowed to call methods on the variable itself. If you want MyClass to be unmodifiable, I'd recommend an interface that only has a getter for .a, then pass that to whoever is using myclass instead of a full reference to the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can better create an interface instead of creating a readonly class. You can return value types and immutable objects from your interface. You can try to create a read-only interface and then your type can implement it. So with this you can pass the type with your interface to code which will only perform reads.

Comment: will I need one interface for each variable type in my class? so for example one interface for int, string, object etc..?

Comment: No, you can have one interface, IMyClass for want of a better name, which can contain a property for each variable you want to expose. If you want it to be modifiable give it get; and set;, if you want it readonly just give it get;. If you are referencing other classes as properties in IMyClass and want them to be immutable, you'll want to hide those behind interfaces too.

Comment: @CallumBradbury but I want to access its properties only from private instance, while the public should have readonly properties

Comment: that's fine, that's the whole point of interfaces. Go do some reading up on interfaces and it will all become apparent